# Replace is not working

Tags: jquery, html

```
var full_text=$(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td").text();
//The above will give me "Subcategory:Mutual Funds"

var sub_text=$(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td a").text();
//The above will give "Subcategory"

var next_text=$(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td").text().substring(14,30);
//The above will give "Mutual Funds"
```

I want to replace `Subcategory` with `Mutual Funds`. So I used the below code,but it is not working.KIndly guide me on the same.

```
var output=full_text.replace(sub_text,next_text);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only changing the text in code and not in the `DOM` where your element is on the page. You need to update the new text in the `DOM` using the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

See the comments inline in the code:

```
var full_text = $(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td");
// full_text is now jQuery object

var sub_text = $(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td a").text();
var next_text = $(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td").text().substring(14, 30);

full_text.text(full_text.text().replace(sub_text, next_text));
// Update the innerText of full_text after replacing the text.
```

Comment: Could you please explain.I dint get it.Even after using theis code.Its not showing the replace functionality

Comment: @bhavyagh Added description in answer

Comment: hi,,I have used the same code.Unfortunately its not working even after the changeUnable to figure out the problem

Comment: @bhavyagh Can you create demo on jsfiddle.net of the same

Comment: Hi Tushar.Its in the sharepoint environment.Don't know how i can show the demo

Comment: Its showing an error "full_text.replace is not a function"

Comment: yes i have checked.But its giving me "full_text.replace is not a function" error

Comment: For this line of code also i m getting "full_text.replace is not a function" error.Not able to figure out the issue

Comment: var full_text = $(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td");
// full_text is now jQuery object

var sub_text = $(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td a").text();
var next_text = $(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td").text().substring(14, 30);

$(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td").text(full_text.replace(sub_text, next_text));

       This is the complete code I have copied.Kindly Check

Comment: @bhavyagh My mistake. `full_text.text(full_text.text().replace(sub_text, next_text));` Check updated answer

Comment: Subcategory : Mutual Funds (4)

Comment: Subcategory : SMAs (6)

Comment: Subcategory : UCITS (1)

Comment: These are the 3 lines in which i have to replace subcategory with the corresponding text after ":".But with the above code lines each line getting replaced with "Subcategory : Mutual Funds (4)Subcategory : UCITS (1)Subcategory : SMAs (6) "

Comment: @bhavyagh Can't tell until I see complete code. Please create `jsfiddle`, so that your problem can be solved

Comment: SInce this is sharepoint environment.Only the above code lines are written by me..Rest is all rendered code.Please guide me on how to proceed with the demo creation

Comment: @bhavyagh Can you get the rendered HTML source

Comment: <td colspan="100" nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-gb"><a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('4-1_', 'img_4-1_',event, false);return false;"><span class="ms-commentcollapse-iconouter"><img class="ms-commentcollapse-icon" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23" alt="expand" id="img_4-1_"></span>Subcategory</a> : Mutual Funds <span style="font-weight: lighter; display: inline-block;">(4)</span></td>

Comment: The above rendered code is for "Subcategory : Mutual Funds (4)"

Comment: for each of this lines i shd be replacing the "Subcategory" with the text which comes after ":"